# Software to change American punctuation to British

Tags: american-english, punctuation, british-english

My apologies if this is off topic.

American and British writing have different punctuation styles. Is there any software that can change American style punctuation to British? I am referring to punctuation, not spelling. A simple example would be changing the American styled

> "Hello," he said.

to what (I think is) the British styled

> 'Hello', he said.

I am not entirely certain about the particulars which is why I need this tool in the first place.

Comment: The "British" style includes punctuation inside the quotes if it's part of the quoted phrase, so while conversion from "British" to "American" is trivial, it's lossy, making 100% accurate conversion from "American" to "British" impossible.

Comment: It's also not really possible to define "British". I use double-quotes first because they don't get confused with apostrophes; and I was taught that at school.

Comment: I have to edit a text that is a horrible jumble of what I consider American and what I consider British punctuation styles. All I really want is to make it consistent, one style or the other and I would like to do it automatically. Perhaps a general "punctuation corrector"? Pretty sure it won't exist but I thought I'd ask.

Comment: sed "s/,\"/\",/g"

Comment: I sent this to Writers.SE because I think they can help you there.